# Indented block error on "Elif" part of assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, My TA (Teachers Assistant) E-mailed me back and told me the code I was looking for in my previous post. I am trying to get various letters and symbols to become turtle commands. Here is my current code:

```
import turtle
command = str(input("enter a  command line"))
length = int(input("enter a length"))
angle = float(input("enter an angle"))

commandLength = len(command)
for i in range(commandLength):
if(command[i] == 'h'):

elif(command[i] == 'h'):
```

OK, My TA was E-mailing me from his cell phone, so he probably couldn't be real specific. But he told me to copy everything in my "if" command line and just put "ELIF" in front of it. When I do that I get an "indentation error"  "expected an indented block" The error is on the line my elif statement is on. Anyone who knows me by now, knows how utterly new I am to programming. Can someone tell me why I am getting the error, and how to fix it or if I am writing this correctly. Thank You.

Comment: Being new to programming isn't an excuse for not learning the basics and reading the documentation of the language you want to program in; or generally for not doing any research. This site isn't a forum and it's not intended for teaching programming basics - in fact, a requirement of a question is to _demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved_ (quoted from the flagging reason I just chose for this). The [introductory chapter](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) of the python tutorial contains all the information you need to solve this by yourself.

Comment: I did suggest an alternative - read material designed to teach the language ("nice" costs extra). But as you've received the same link in the answer to your first question 8 days ago, yet still haven't grasped the basic fact that python's control flow is determined by indentation (quote from the linked chapter: "indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements"), you don't seem to invest much into learning. Your questions up to now didn't show any effort on your part; you can't expect any help when you fail to demonstrate your willingness to learn and do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
command = str(input("enter a  command line"))
length = int(input("enter a length"))
angle = float(input("enter an angle"))

commandLength = len(command)
for i in range(commandLength):
    if(command[i] == 'h'):

    elif(command[i] == 'h'):
```

Every block should be indented.

A block is everything with `:` at the end.